Consulta para limpiar Fragment
Muy buenas esperando que todos se encuentren muy bien, soy un novato en las lides de android bajo java y terminando mi primera app, me encontré con un problema, poseo cuatro fragment, los cuales están de esta forma, primero el xml del activity:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".archivos.Frmpresupuesto">

<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tablayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#BA85D3C8">

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
        android:id="@+id/ingreso"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Ingreso"
        android:textColor="@color/tab_color"
        android:icon="@drawable/ingresar"/>

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
        android:id="@+id/mano"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Mano"
        android:textColor="@color/tab_color"
        android:icon="@drawable/mano"/>

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
        android:id="@+id/repuestos"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Repuestos"
        android:textColor="@color/tab_color"
        android:icon="@drawable/repuestos"/>

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
        android:id="@+id/resumen"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Resumen"
        android:textColor="@color/tab_color"
        android:icon="@drawable/resumen"/>
</com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>

<androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />


posteriormente este es el java del activity:
public class Frmpresupuesto extends AppCompatActivity{

TabLayout tabLayout;
ViewPager viewPager;
TabItem tab1, tab2, tab3, tab4;
PagerController pagerAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_frmpresupuesto);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    setTitle("Ingreso de Presupuestos");
    tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tablayout);
    viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    tab1 = findViewById(R.id.ingreso);
    tab2 = findViewById(R.id.mano);
    tab3 = findViewById(R.id.repuestos);
    tab4 = findViewById(R.id.resumen);

    for (int i = 0; i < tabLayout.getTabCount(); i++) {
        TabLayout.Tab tab = tabLayout.getTabAt(i);
        if (tab != null) {
            Drawable icon = tab.getIcon();
            if (icon != null) {
                icon.setColorFilter(Color.DKGRAY, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
            }
        }
    }

    viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1);

    pagerAdapter = new PagerController(getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());

    viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
    tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        }
    });

    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    // Guardar el estado del ViewPager
    outState.putInt("viewPagerPosition", viewPager.getCurrentItem());
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    // Restaurar el estado del ViewPager
    int viewPagerPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt("viewPagerPosition");
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(viewPagerPosition);
}

public void setLimpiarDatos() {
    //Encuentra el fragmento "repuestos" y limpia sus datos
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    repuestos fragmentRepuestos = (repuestos) fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("tercero");
    if (fragmentRepuestos != null) {
        fragmentRepuestos.actualizarLimpiarDatos();
    }

    // Encuentra el fragmento "resumen" y limpia sus datos
    resumen fragmentResumen = (resumen) fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("cuarto");
    if (fragmentResumen != null) {
        fragmentResumen.actualizarLimpiarDatos();
    }
}

ahora al momento de hacerlo correr y me presenta los cuatro fragment en el tabulador, por lo cual lo primero que se hace en el fragment llamado ingreso se carga la patente que uno escoge por ejemplo SJTX46, después se va a los otros tres fragment y uno hace click en el botón de búsqueda por patente y carga todos los datos, hasta el último, posteriormente después de hacer uno puede modificar, eliminar es decir todo, ahora lo que se pretende que el usuario vuelva al primer fragment y que haga click en el botón limpiar, el cual realiza el siguiente proceso:
private void Limpiardatos (){
    limpiarDatos1 = true;
    // Transacción para el segundo fragmento (manoFragment)
    mano manoFragment = new mano();
    Bundle argsMano = new Bundle();
    argsMano.putBoolean("limpiarDatos1", limpiarDatos1);
    manoFragment.setArguments(argsMano);
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getParentFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction1 = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    transaction1.replace(R.id.segundo, manoFragment);
    transaction1.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction1.commit();
    EventBus.getDefault().post(new LimpiarDatosEvent(limpiarDatos1));

    Frmpresupuesto actividad = (Frmpresupuesto) requireActivity();
    actividad.setLimpiarDatos();

    // Transacción para el tercer fragmento (repuestosFragment)
    /*repuestos repuestosFragment = new repuestos();
    Bundle argsRepuestos = new Bundle();
    argsRepuestos.putBoolean("limpiarDatos1", limpiarDatos1);
    repuestosFragment.setArguments(argsRepuestos);
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.tercero, repuestosFragment)
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .commit();
    EventBus.getDefault().post(new LimpiarDatosEvent(limpiarDatos1));*/

    // Transacción para el cuarto fragmento (resumenFragment)
    /*resumen resumenFragment = new resumen();
    Bundle argsResumen = new Bundle();
    argsResumen.putBoolean("limpiarDatos1", limpiarDatos1);
    resumenFragment.setArguments(argsResumen);
    FragmentTransaction transaction3 = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    transaction3.replace(R.id.cuarto, resumenFragment);
    transaction3.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction3.commit();
    EventBus.getDefault().post(new LimpiarDatosEvent(limpiarDatos1));*/
    txtpresupuesto1.setText("");
    txtnombre4.setText("");
    txtrut4.setText("");
    txtfecha1.setText("");
    txtnombre5.setText("");
    txtsiniestro.setText("");
    txtnombre6.setText("");
    txtfono4.setText("");
    txttercero.setText("");
    txtfonotercero.setText("");
    txtmarca2.setText("");
    txtmodelo1.setText("");
    txtano.setText("");
    txtpatente.setText("");
    txtchasis.setText("");
    a.setText("");
    b.setText("");
    c.setText("");
    d.setText("");
    e.setText("");
    f.setText("");
    tbldatos1.removeAllViews();
    sppatente.setAdapter(null);
    ArrayList<String> seleccion4 = new ArrayList<>();
    seleccion4.add("Seleccione patente");
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adaptador4 = new ArrayAdapter (getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, seleccion4);
    sppatente.setAdapter(adaptador4);
    spcompania.setAdapter(null);
    ArrayList<String> seleccion = new ArrayList<>();
    seleccion.add("Seleccione Cliente");
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adaptador = new ArrayAdapter (getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, seleccion);
    spcompania.setAdapter(adaptador);
    spliquidador.setAdapter(null);
    ArrayList<String> seleccion1 = new ArrayList<>();
    seleccion1.add("Seleccione Liquidador");
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adaptador1 = new ArrayAdapter (getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, seleccion1);
    spliquidador.setAdapter(adaptador1);
    spmarca.setAdapter(null);
    ArrayList<String> seleccion2 = new ArrayList<>();
    seleccion2.add("Seleccione Marca");
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adaptador2 = new ArrayAdapter (getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, seleccion2);
    spmarca.setAdapter(adaptador2);
    spmodelo.setAdapter(null);
    ArrayList<String> seleccion3 = new ArrayList<>();
    seleccion3.add("Seleccione Modelo");
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adaptador3 = new ArrayAdapter (getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, seleccion3);
    spmodelo.setAdapter(adaptador3);
    shouldLoadSpinner1 = false;
    btn_modificar.setEnabled(false);
    btn_eliminar.setEnabled(false);
    btn_grabar.setEnabled(true);
    llenarSpinner();
}

@Subscribe
public void onLimpiarDatosEvent(LimpiarDatosEvent event) {

}

en este deje en comentario que hubo problemas en las transacciones, ya que en el tercer fragment de repuestos me indicaba que no existía el id llamado tercero, por lo cual tambien les presento dicho xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/tercero"
android:tag="@+id/tercero"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:padding="1dp"
android:background="@drawable/fondo"
tools:context=".archivos.repuestos">

ante lo cual se hizo el siguiente cambio ya descrito anteriormente:
Frmpresupuesto actividad = (Frmpresupuesto) requireActivity();
    actividad.setLimpiarDatos();

ante lo cual les vuelvo a presentar el código del proceso que se hace en el java del activity:
public void setLimpiarDatos() {
    //Encuentra el fragmento "repuestos" y limpia sus datos
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    repuestos fragmentRepuestos = (repuestos) fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("tercero");
    if (fragmentRepuestos != null) {
        fragmentRepuestos.actualizarLimpiarDatos();
    }

    // Encuentra el fragmento "resumen" y limpia sus datos
    resumen fragmentResumen = (resumen) fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("cuarto");
    if (fragmentResumen != null) {
        fragmentResumen.actualizarLimpiarDatos();
    }
}

ante lo cual, no entra ya que me indica que fragmentRepuestos = null y fragmentResumen = null, pero les presento imagenes que estan los datos ya cargados y hay.

y otra misma del fargment llamado repuestos

Espero que me puedan ayudar en este problema, llevo mas de dos semanas en esto y nadie me ha podiso prestar ayuda, además he buscado por todos lados e investigado ya que no me gusta molestar, pero siempre dan ejemplos con el Drawn navigation, ojala que lo haya nombrado bien, si necesitan algo mas no duden en solictarlo y esperando una buena acogida y desde ya muchas gracias.
